# Hikaricp jdbc authentication in a multi-tenant architecture

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant, hikaricp

I have a multi-tenant SaaS application where all tenants use a single database on a Mysql server. Each tenant authenticates against Mysql using its own username to prevent cross-tenant access. I am trying to use Hikaricp  for pooling, but it seems that Hikaricp does not support this scenario with several database users. I am using Mariadb jdbc 2.5.0 and Hikaricp 3.4.1. Has someone experienced this same problem?

Comment: HikariCP (or any other connection pool manager) will just create a pool of logical connections (sessions in the DB) with the arguments you provide to it. You can even create multiple connection pools, each one with its own set of connection parameters. The idea of these conn pools is not to log in every time but to lend you a DB session to execute something and then you return it to the pool to be used by any other process. The logic you intend to create must be managed somewhere else.

Comment: My problem is that it lends me an already authenticated connection. I am not seeing other alternative other than not using a connection pool at all or use a single user to connect to Mysql for all my tenants.